# Using iif function in checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, eval, iif

I am working in a project where I need to display data from database in a gridview. The gridview contains `varchar` fields could be whether YES or NO. So I want to display rather than the text, checkbox. When its YES check box will be checked, when its NO check box will be unchecked.

My asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheck" runat="server" Checked='<%#"IIF(Eval("Check")="YES",true,false)%>' Width="80px" Enabled="false"/>
```

I am getting this error:

`Character constant must contain exactly one character.`

Is there any alternative option would solve my issue?

Comment: There are a lot of extra quotes...

Comment: @NaveedButt even when I remove it, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: try this: `'<%#IIf(Eval("Check")="YES",true,false)%>'`. The 'f' in `IIf` is small case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this (for VB.NET)

```
Checked='<%#  Eval("Check")="YES" %>'
```

For null values try

```
Checked='<%#  Convert.ToString(Eval("Check"))="Yes" %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your error, but do you need the `IIF`? I'm no expert in ASP, I'm relatively new to it, but why can't you just do `Checked='<%# Eval("Checked") == "yes" %>'`? And beyond that what about `Checked='<%# Item.Checked == "yes" %>'`?

Comment: When what field is null?

Comment: Oh, I see below that Checked can be a DBNull. That explains a lot. `Item.Checked == DBNull.Value ? Item.Checked == "yes" : false` should do the trick.

Comment: it gave me this error: `'Item' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Answer (score 0):

Performance hint: Use DataRowView instead of Eval within the GridView control:

```
Checked='<%# (((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Check"].ToString() == "YES") ? true : false %>'
```

Comment: I cannot use Data in expression, it gives me an error.